# How to repeat an action with offset in NLA?

Tags: nla-editor

Reading up to answer my question it seems that Blender once had an offset setting in NLA for use in conjunction with Repeat but that has been replaced with something else. I can't find out what it is.

I tried making a simple animation of the default cube of just a few keystrokes using the timeline and then using Cycles with Offset in the graph editor to repeat the action. Fine, but when viewed in the Action Editor, the repeat cycles cannot be seen and when pushed down to the NLA, the action strip is just the basic timeline animation with no repeats.

If I want to make an action strip comprising say 20 repeats of a cycle WITH OFFSET how can I push that action into the NLA or its cache so I can then use the full strip at will?

Comment: Look into *ADD* blending mode for NLA strip. Basically every copied NLA strip will be added to previous one

Comment: Can't find much on this. If I change Blending from Replace to Add it irrevocably doubles the size of the object (scaled at 1.0) in the first instance of the strip and does not offset transform on subsequent ones. I am putting them on the same NlaTrack. .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it this way, you have to increase the lenght of the action manually. You can also use the Repeat function of the NLA editor below the red frame.
[image]

Comment: The repeat function in NLA has no offset function so building even this simple action manually seems to be the answer as you say. I can script it to make it easier.